# How to get a variable from functions.php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'am styling my webpage and in my function.php file I have written some code which I wanna access from the elementor html code button.

```
<td width='25%'><input type='text' id='uptname' name='uptname' value=<?php echo $name ?></td>
```

the value is not printed. normally the value from my database is supposed to be displayed. Thats my part in the functions.php file.

```
if (isset($_GET['upt'])) {
    $upt_id = $_GET['up'];
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM gemeinde WHERE id='$upt_id'");
    foreach($result as $print) {
        $name = $print->name;
    }
}
```

either the id field or the gemeinde field is supposed to show the results from my database.
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would help if you could add more information to your question. 
In general, you cannot access a function from elementor directly. If you want to display the result of a function, you should probably look into shortcodes:https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/ These look like '[video title='bla']' and can then be inserted in any WYSIWYG block in Wordpress.

Comment: Well the field id='uptname' name='uptname' so which field are you trying to GET ?

Comment: try value="<?php echo $name ?>" instead of value=<?php echo $name ?>  See for "  " quotes for value attributes..

Comment: "<?php echo $name ?>" doesn't work. I tried it but that shows just the written code. :(

Comment: ok... change $upt_id = $_GET['up'];  TO  $upt_id = $_GET['upt'];

Comment: That's not the issue :D. I wanna display the database. so the problem is that the HTML code is not showing the results which I saved in the $name

Answer (score 0):

You should try: `<td width='25%'><input type='text' id='uptname' name='uptname' value='<?php echo $name ?>'></td>`

You just forgot to put quotes around `<?php ... ?>` and close correctly the `<td>` node.

Comment: Doesn't work. The output is "<?php echo $name ?>"

Comment: Then probably the extension of your file is `.html` when it should be `.php`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (isset($_GET['upt'])) {
  $upt_id = $_GET['up'];
  $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM gemeinde WHERE id='$upt_id'");
    foreach($result as $print) {
      $name = $print->name;
    }
}
```

To

```
if (isset($_GET['upt'])) {
  $upt_id = $_GET['upt']; //up changed by upt
  $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->gemeinde WHERE id='$upt_id'");
   foreach($result as $print) {
      $name = $print->name;
   }
}
```

And

Change

```
<td width='25%'><input type='text' id='uptname' name='uptname' value=<?php echo $name ?></td>
```

To

```
<td width='25%'><input type='text' id='uptname' name='uptname' value='<?php echo $name ?>'></td> // See for input tag close and  quotes around value
```

** The attribute value can remain unquoted if it doesn’t contain spaces or any of " or ' . Otherwise, it has to be quoted using either single or double quotes. The value, along with the = character, can be omitted altogether if the value is the empty string.

Comment: $name = $print->name; is changed to $name = $print['name'];

Comment: Doesn't work. The output is "<?php echo $name ?>"

Comment: try changing $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM gemeinde WHERE id='$upt_id'"); TO $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->gemeinde WHERE id='$upt_id'"); AND Also reset $name = $print['name;]; TO $name = $print->name;